How to reformat current date/time into a variable for use in a "where" clause
If I run the following Oracle SQL query:
SELECT foo_number
FROM bar_log;

I have records that look like this:
20240621.16^123ABCD^SEARCH_PROFILE^AB1C3^9999

The first string (20240621.16) is a timestamp (YYYYMMDD.HH); the hour is reflected in 24-hour format, but hours with single digits do not have a leading zero. I would like to take the current date/time, convert it to reflect this timestamp format as a variable and use the variable in a WHERE clause to find records that match. What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

You can use to_char() to convert a date/time to a string. Usually the HH24 format element gives leading zeros, which you don't want; but if you precede that element with the FM format modifier it does not.
Running now at 11pm, that gives '23' for the hour; in an hour's time it will give '0' for midnight, not '00.
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24') from dual




TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24')




20240621.23



select to_char(sysdate + 1/24, 'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24') from dual




TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+1/24,'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24')




20240622.0



select to_char(sysdate + 6/24, 'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24') from dual




TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+6/24,'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24')




20240622.5



fiddle
You can then use that however you need:
...
where foo_number like to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24') || '^%'

Or even simpler, embedding the fixed characters in the format so you don't need to concatenate:
...
where foo_number like to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD.FMHH24"^%"')

fiddle

Thank you; this works perfectly for my application!

Take the sub-string up until the character before the first ^ character and then use TO_DATE:
SELECT TO_DATE(
         SUBSTR(foo_number, 1, INSTR(foo_number, '^') - 1),
         'YYYYMMDD"."HH24'
       ) AS dt
FROM   bar_log;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE bar_log (foo_number) AS
SELECT '20240621.16^123ABCD^SEARCH_PROFILE^AB1C3^9999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20240621.1^123ABCD^SEARCH_PROFILE^AB1C3^9999' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DT




2024-06-21 16:00:00


2024-06-21 01:00:00




If you want to filter based on SYSDATE then you can use:
SELECT foo_number
FROM   bar_log
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         SUBSTR(foo_number, 1, INSTR(foo_number, '^') - 1),
         'YYYYMMDD"."HH24'
       ) <= SYSDATE;

Which outputs:



FOO_NUMBER




20240621.16^123ABCD^SEARCH_PROFILE^AB1C3^9999


20240621.1^123ABCD^SEARCH_PROFILE^AB1C3^9999



fiddle
